# android-bootstrap-widgetsの使い方

Tags: android, android-bootstrap

android-bootstrap 2.xバージョンを使用しておりまして、こちら https://github.com/Bearded-Hen/Android-Bootstrap の公式サイトを見たのですが、xmlでの例はあるのですが、
使い方が書いていません。xmlでの使い方のドキュメントはどこにあるのでしょうか？
どなたかご協力お願い致します。